# Sitecore patch file help needed

Tags: solr, configuration, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm trying to patch the solr configurations with patch file below. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Basically I'm trying to replace/override the default core with our own naming convention per environment.

Could someone please review what am I doing wrong here:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<Sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
        <configuration>
            <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
                <index id="sitecore_master_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                   <patch:attribute param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                    <param desc="rebuildcore">"siteA_dev_$(id)_swap"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_core_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_analytics_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_testing_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_suggested_test_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_fxm_master_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_fxm_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_list_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="social_messages_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="social_messages_web" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                </index>
                <index id="sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">"siteA_dev_$(id)"</param>
                </index>
            </indexes>
        </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
    <settings>
        <setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress">
            <patch:attribute name="value">http://localhost:8983/solr</patch:attribute>
        </setting>
    </settings>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: *it doesn't seem to be working* — how exactly? The configuration doesn't change at all, or?..

Comment: yep, config doesn't change the core value doesn't get changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `patch:attribute`. Your changing the value of the tag.

```xml
<index id="sitecore_master_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <param desc="core" patch:instead="param[@desc='core']">siteA_dev_$(id)</param>
</index>
```

`patch:attribute` can be used to change xml attribute only, e.g. if you want to change the value of the `type` attribute of `<index>` tag:

```xml
<index id="sitecore_master_index">
    <patch:attribute name="type">Custom.Type.Goes.Here</patch:attribute>
</index>
```

Comment: I get below Marek:
Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex. No matching constructor was found.

Comment: This happens when your patch file in included **before** the original index definition. Sitecore tries to create a new Index object with only 1 parameter and there is no constructor with only 1 parameter. Make sure you put your patch file in `/App_Config/Include/ZZZ.MyPatches` folder or some other folder which will start with `Z` letter.

Comment: Thank you, that error is gone. Regarding Solr, does the solr core name on Solr Admin must match the name of core folder? e.g. I created core  name as siteA_dev_core_index and provided the folder path to /siteA/dev/core_index

Comment: To be honest I don't know. I've never tried to use folder name different than core name.

Comment: Hi Marek, i'm facing one more issue. I would like to add "rebuildcore" element as part of patch. I used below but it isnt' working:
<index id="sitecore_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                    <param desc="core">contentsite_dev_$(id)</param>
     <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">contentsite_dev_$(id)_swap</param>
                </index>

Comment: Try without `patch:after`

Comment: Unfortunately I get this exception if I remove patch:after part:Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex. No matching constructor was found.

Comment: Fixed now thank you. I had to first replace the attribute and do patch:after